# Buildr - Filter web.xml in packaging war

Tags: buildr

Is it possible to filter the web.xml file when packaging a war using Buildr?

Buildr documentation:

> Without much prompting, package :war picks the contents of the
>   src/main/webapp directory and places it at the root of the WAR

I have a place holder or token defined in the web.xml and I would like to replace it when packaging the war depending on which env I am building. What is the best way to go about it? Is there a filtering option for the package method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can instruct Buildr to filter your resources under `src/main/webapp` and place the resulting files under `target/webapp`,

```
filter_webapp = file("target/webapp") do |task|
  filter('src/main/webapp/').into(task.to_s).using(
    'version' => '9999'
  ).run
end
```

then wire your new task with the resources tasks (which is implicitly required before packaging),

```
resources.enhance [filter_webapp]
```

and finally package the filtered resources,

```
package(:war).with(filter_webapp)
```

For more details about filtering, see http://buildr.apache.org/building.html#resources

Comment: thanks Alex for the response. I haven't got it working yet though, will be away for couple of days but will continue with this when I am back

Comment: Hi Alex, this works thanks...reason it was failing earlier was with this error:ArgumentError : symbol string may not contain '\0' on line filter('src/main...). Narrowed it down to a jpeg file in my images folder...strange as the other jpegs / gifs / etc are fine. Soon as I remove that image it works

Comment: I get an `ArgumentError : interning empty string` at the second line. buildr --trace doesn't help me.

Comment: Is it possible to specify single files / a concrete set of files to be treated and not the complete directory?